# removing a json array object item if it matches a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, fs

In my index file, I am accessing this json using fs. I am trying to remove one of the array object items where a string input in my external index.js file matches the value of the "ChannelName" key.

I have tried finding the index of the item where the channelname matches the string input but this didn't work(Converted to an array to try this).

Has anyone any ideas? Is this even possible?

```html
{
    "DiscordServerId":"",
    "token":"",
    "twitch_clientID":"",
    "twitch_secret":"",
    "cron":"*/10 * * * *",
    "channelID":"",
    "roleID":"everyone",
    "channels":[
        {
            "ChannelName":"channel1",
            "DiscordServer":"",
            "twitch_stream_id":"",
            "discord_nessage_id":""},
        {
            "ChannelName":"channel2",
            "DiscordServer":"",
            "twitch_stream_id":"",
            "discord_nessage_id":""
        },
        {
            "ChannelName":"channel2",
            "DiscordServer":"",
            "twitch_stream_id":"",
            "discord_nessage_id":""
        }
    ],
    "authToken":""}
```

Comment: Show us what you actually tried. _Always._

Comment: _"I have tried finding the index of the item where the channelname matches the string input"_ - Where's that attempt?

Comment: A snippet only makes sense when there's something to execute and that execution adds relevant information to the question (specific behavior, an error, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `channels` with some condition.

```js
const searchChannelName = "channel2";
const data = {
  "DiscordServerId": "",
  "token": "",
  "twitch_clientID": "",
  "twitch_secret": "",
  "cron": "*/10 * * * *",
  "channelID": "",
  "roleID": "everyone",
  "channels": [
    {
      "ChannelName": "channel1",
      "DiscordServer": "",
      "twitch_stream_id": "",
      "discord_nessage_id": ""
    },
    {
      "ChannelName": "channel2",
      "DiscordServer": "",
      "twitch_stream_id": "",
      "discord_nessage_id": ""
    },
    {
      "ChannelName": "channel2",
      "DiscordServer": "",
      "twitch_stream_id": "",
      "discord_nessage_id": ""
    }
  ],
  "authToken": ""
}
data.channels = data.channels.filter((node => node.ChannelName !== searchChannelName));
console.log(data);
```